# Декомпиляция unity android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, декомпиляция

Я хотел бы локализировать android приложение написанное на unity. Я читал в интернете про декомпиляцию для локализации, но почти все статьи написаны для Windows игр. Каким образом можно декомпилировать apk для перевода?

Comment: Google -> "unity android decompilation" имеет множество результатов подходящих под твой запрос. Заметь, я буквально использовал заголовок твоего вопроса на английском и получил кучу результатов. А так вообще согласен с ответом Алексея Шиманского.

Answer (score 2):

Самое верное - обратиться к разработчику и спросить у него разрешение во-первых на возможность локализации, во-вторых на само сотрудничество. И уже по договорённости оформляете либо репозиторий для пулл реквеста, либо ещё что-то. Но работаете уже непосредственно с автором.

Comment: Я согласен. Но я чисто для себя хочу

Comment: Что-то я вам не верю.

Comment: В любом случае, правильный путь - через автора. Это будет и вам хорошо и, если всё получится, для остальных тоже. И, возможно, даже можно будет договориться о небольшом royalty

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi проблема декомпиляции состоит в том, что ломать не строить, в код это развернуть можно, но вот опять скомпилировать в исполняемый файл довольно проблематично

Comment: Вот только проект китайский, кого попало они вряд-ли возьмут. Да и в игре только китайский язык (вряд-ли они собираются локализировать). Я думаю, что все же не так сложно значение компонента text (или TextMeshPro) отредактировать

Comment: @Mr.Dandomi `кого попало они вряд-ли возьмут` - а вы попробовали? Есть еще вариант: найти хорошую студию-локализатора, которые могут переводить игры, далее пойти к разработчику и спросить, не желают ли они перевести свой проект на английский и русский. Если все согласны - сводите вместе студию-локализатора и разработчика игры. И дальше они сами всё сделают за вас и для вас и по деньгам между собой тоже сами рассчитаются.